# Is the theme of naming intentional?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, luke-cage-2016

Several episodes into the second season of *Luke Cage*, I've noticed what seems to be an intentional pattern:

- Bushmaster insists that Mariah Dillard is Mariah *Stokes*, tying her to her relatives involved in organized crime.
- Luke's father insists on calling him Carl. Luke insists that his name is Luke, the name he chose.
- Mariah calls Stephanie Billie, because she thinks she has her number (but of course, she doesn't)...
- Luke doesn't want people producing drugs with this name on them.
- Bushmaster seems to love telling people his name.

It seems as if there's a definite theme of names, and who controls them.

Has anyone associated with the show commented on whether this theme was intentional?

Comment: I’m not quite sure what your question is? The theme of people calling other people by names other than their preferred names?

Comment: @Edlothiad - I thought it was clear. The theme of the power and meaning of names. What does it mean to be a Dillard vs a Stokes, Carl vs. Luke?